# Outlook add-on - manifest file issue

Tags: outlook-addin, manifest

I am trying to build my first add-on for Outlook and have gotten stuck with my manifest.xml file. Here are the errors from the validator I have come across:

**Error #1:**
XML Schema Validation Error: Error found during XML Schema validation.

- Details: The element 'OfficeApp' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1' has invalid child element 'VersionOverrides' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1'. List of possible elements expected: 'Rule' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1'.
- Line: 33
- Column: 6

**Error #2:**
XML Schema Violation: Your manifest does not adhere to the current set of XML schema definitions for Office Add-in manifests.
**The manifest is not valid.**

I have tried to look through the documentation, but unfortunately could not find a straight forward answer on how to resolve it, hence any clue from you guys would be much appreciated.

Here is my xml code:

````
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
           xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1"
           xsi:type="MailApp">
    <Id>34e6280c-0410-4bd3-a394-6b14f96e4057</Id>
    <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    <ProviderName>Home.pl</ProviderName>
    <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
    <DisplayName DefaultValue="Analysis"/>
    <Description DefaultValue="Check for analysis."/>
    <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:8000/static/images/icon_32.jpg"/>
    <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:8000/static/images/icon_80.jpg"/>
    <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:8000/"/>
    <Hosts>
        <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
    </Hosts>
    <Requirements>
        <Sets>
            <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1"/>
        </Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <FormSettings>
        <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
            <DesktopSettings>
                <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:8000/sentiment/src/taskpane/taskpane.html"/>
                <RequestedHeight>450</RequestedHeight>
            </DesktopSettings>
        </Form>
    </FormSettings>
    <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
        <Description resid="residDescription" />
        <Requirements>
            <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
                <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
            </bt:Sets>
        </Requirements>
        <Hosts>
            <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
                <DesktopFormFactor>
                    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
                        <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                            <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                                <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
                                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                                    <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel"/>
                                    <Supertip>
                                        <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle"/>
                                        <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription"/>
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:8000/static/images/icon_16.jpg"/>
                                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:8000/static/images/icon_32.jpg"/>
                                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:8000/static/images/icon_80.jpg"/>
                                    </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                        <SourceLocation resid="readTaskPaneURL"/>
                                    </Action>
                                </Control>
                            </Group>
                        </OfficeTab>
                    </ExtensionPoint>
                </DesktopFormFactor>
            </Host>
        </Hosts>
        <Resources>
            <bt:Images>
                <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:8000/static/images/icon_16.jpg"/>
                <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:8000/static/images/icon_32.jpg"/>
                <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:8000/static/images/icon_80.jpg"/>
            </bt:Images>
            <bt:Urls>
                <bt:Url id="readTaskPaneURL" DefaultValue="https://localhost:8000/sentiment/src/taskpane/taskpane.html"/>
            </bt:Urls>
            <bt:ShortStrings>
                <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="Sentiment Analysis"/>
                <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Analyze Sentiment"/>
                <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Sentiment Analysis"/>
            </bt:ShortStrings>
            <bt:LongStrings>
                <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Click to analyze the sentiment of the email content."/>
            </bt:LongStrings>
        </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>```
````

Comment: The error says everything ... you are missing the required `Rule` element. Please see the [Mail application required elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/xml-manifest-overview?tabs=tabid-1#required-elements-by-office-add-in-type).